# Reading the content of the file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

- **tools/tech stack:** Serenity BDD,Java ,chrome browser

**Scenario to automate:** user clicks on a button,a file "**https"//appurl/pdfstatement.aspx?xxx**"opens in other tab in chrome.

**Note:** when Manually downloaded the file and file is downloaded as .pdf

**Question: how to read the text from this file**

**Question1:** How to click on download icon/button as this button appears when mouse hover in that section

**Tried Solution 1:** for trying to download the file

```
 WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    Set<String> set = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator it = set.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
           driver.switchTo().window((String) it.next());
    }
    //String Currentlink = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    driver.getCurrentUrl();
    withAction().moveToElement(target1).build().perform();
```

**Question2** : How to download the file without opening it in next tab

**Tried Solution 2:** disabling chrome preference as pdfj.disabled=true but still file is opened in new tab

```
String userDir = System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\Downloads";

        try {

        PDDocument document = null;             
               document = PDDocument.load(fp);                      
               String pdfContent = new PDFTextStripper().getText(document);*/

               //Loading an existing document.Code below works if pdf file exists in dir

               File file = new File(userDir+"//PDFStatement.pdf");
              PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);

              //Instantiate PDFTextStripper class
              PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

              //Retrieving text from PDF document
              String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
              System.out.println(text);

              //Closing the document
              document.close();
```

**Tried solution 3:** download the file using wget
C:>cmd /c C:\wget.exe -P C:\Wget --no-check-certificate https://appUrl/PDFStatement.aspx?registrationid=xxxx&facilitycode=xxxx&TranType=PDF

This doesnot download the contents or the pdf file but"PDFStatement.aspx@registrationid=xxxxx" file which has some html tags.

Serenity.Properties

```
chrome_preferences.download.default_directory=${user.home}\\Downloads
chrome_preferences.downloadPath=${user.home}\\Downloads
chrome_preferences.download.prompt_for_download=false 
chrome_preferences.pdfjs.disabled=True
```

How can I achieve my target of reading the contents of the file.is there any way apart from what I have tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: This seems suspiciously close to https://stackoverflow.com/q/60396702/3124333 Posting duplicate questions does not increase the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: yes .question are same. was not ablr to find my question so thought to post again. please close the"stackoverflow.com/q/60396702/3124333" if you can .